# Removing code first migration and degrade to older state

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.1

I have multiple DBContext so I created multiple Code first Migration folders.  I just created another DBContext and related table in the code.  I also added migration folder and applied in database as InitialSetup.  Now I realize that I don't need new changes in DB and code.  I want to remove this Migration folder and revert the database changes that were applied during this Migration.

When I am running command like this:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: ContentAddDownloadPath
```

get this error: 
More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'DnpMVCSite'. Specify the name of the one to use.

When specify the Configuration Path:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationType DnpMVCSite.Migrations.ContentMigration.Configuration –TargetMigration: ContentAddDownloadPath
```

it show the message that "Target database is already at version 201407140515121_ContentAddDownloadPath."

My problem is that I want to remove newly added Migration folder and DB modification done by this migration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just run following command on Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration Step3
Update-Database
```

And you want to rollback it, just run following command

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration Step2
```

`Step2` is the name of the migration before `Step3`.

Then you can remove the `Step3` file and also revert the code changes.

Please check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) as reference on paragraft  **Migrate to a Specific Version (Including Downgrade)**.

## UPDATE

I think what you wanna do is reverting all changes in a specific target migrations folder / target configuration. To do so, you can by specifying `-TargetMigration 0`.

Be cautious that if you do that, all migrations in that directory  / configuration will be reverted even the initial state. For example I have these classes that refer to the same database.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
}
public class AppContext2 : DbContext
{
    public AppContext2()
        : base("AppContext")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

My directory looks like this

[image: Migration Folder]

And if I want to revert all changes in the Migrations2 folder, what I need to do is.

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName PlaygroundTestEF.Migrations2.Configuration -TargetMigration 0
```

Result would be as follow, the city table has been dropped now.

[image: End Result]

Comment: I have already gone through this article and tried to do downgrade.  But it didn't work.  I have updated the question